# what is the size of every memory cell in the stack and is it possible to split one cell

Tags: c, ram

In a 64 bit system every memory cell is 64 bit, so how does it save an int  variable that contains less space?  Wouldn't it spend one 64 bit address any way? If so why bother to use difference types of variables if they going to catch one cell any way.

Comment: @Lundin i see so the only difference is the cpu registers?

Comment: The `sizeof` operator will tell you how many addressable storage units a variable uses. The C standard calls those minimal addressable storage units "bytes" even if they are more than 8 bits wide (but they must be at least 8 bits wide).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of terminology is all over the place.

A *memory cell* typically corresponds to a logic gate on the hardware level and is very likely to be 1 bit large assuming binary computers.

What I think you are asking about is the smallest addressable unit in a computer, also known as a *byte*, which is very likely 8 bits large.

This has nothing to do with the data register width of the CPU, which is what one usually refers to when talking about "64 bit computers". The data register width is the largest chunk of data that the CPU can process in a single instruction, but not necessarily the smallest. And this has no relation with the *address bus width* of the computer, though they are often the same nowadays.

When you declare a variable in C, the size allocated depends on the system. An `int` is for example very likely 32 bit large on all 32 bit and 64 bit computers. Notably, all mainstream 64 bit computers also support 32 bit or smaller instructions. So it doesn't necessarily make sense for the compiler to allocate more memory than 32 bit - you might get larger memory use for no speed gained.

I believe the term you are fishing for is *alignment*. It is only inefficient for the computer to read smaller chunks in case they are allocated on *misaligned addresses*. That is, an address which is not evenly divisible by the data register width (expressed in bytes). Such accesses are typically slower, or in some cases not supported at all. So a 64 bit compiler might therefore decide to allocate a small variable inside a 8 byte chunk, and leave the remaining bytes that aren't used as *padding bytes*. However, in case the compiler optimizes for size, it may chose to store data in a more memory-effective way, at the cost of access time.

Comment: so each address in the stack is 8 bit?

Comment: @dasehaish Yes, on normal mainstream computers. The stack specifically can be used to store all manner of things.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that memory is accessed by cache line size, usually larger than the word size.

Comment: Sorry to notpick but "The data register width is the largest chunk of data that the CPU can process in a single instruction" is not completely accurate since there are architectures with instructions handling several registers at once, like Load and Store Multiple in ARM Thumb instruction set.

Comment: @stark, not really: from the processor point of view, the memory is accessed the same way whether the cache is enabled or not.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean It's kind of hard to make an universal definition. Similarly, there are many 8 bit CPUs that allow you to do a 16 bit atomic accesses to certain registers in a single instruction, by doing two 8 bit access interally, in non-interruptable hardware.

Comment: so basically if you don't wrote in assembly you cant do calculation with 64 bit fast because you don't use the register you use the ram

Comment: @dasehaish: Most compilers will generate code to use registers as much as possible.  It depends on the specific compiler and underlying system.  There's no one-size-fits-all rule.